# Rails / Jquery: not logged in user should be able to add bookmark through modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, cookies

I want to let users bookmark movies on my rails 3.2 app. I'd like to have the bookmark button always displayed on the movie page, even if the user is not logged in. I'm all set with logged in users, but I'm having trouble managing the case when not logged in users are adding a bookmark.

I want to accomplish something similar to what Yelp does when you try to add a bookmark and are not logged in: when a user is not logged in and click on the "Add bookmark" button: 
1. User should see a modal where the user can log in or sign up, 
2. When authentication is successful, bookmark should be added.

At this point, I am using jQuery to make a post request (something like $.post("/bookmark/create", {data: {film_id:1223}...} ) when the user clicks "Add bookmark".

My bookmarks controller then render a create.js.erb file that updates the movie page if the user is logged in (that piece is all good), or displays the signup/login modal when the user is not logged in.

In my modal, I have a form asking for login and password and calling post "account/authenticate_xhr". My problem is that I don't know what to do next to create the bookmark (and I'm not really familiar with jQuery, call backs, and sessions/cookies at this point, and I think all of them are involved...).

What would be good ways to implement what I want? (Don't need the exact code, just to understand what goes in my jQuery file, what goes in the controller, and how they work together).

Thanks!